# Avoiding Not on FX application thread causes UI to crash

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm making a step-by-step based game with JavaFX and I'm using do while loop to wait for user input. The problem is, it's called from a fxml controller initialize method and that means the interface will never load. The solution is to wait using another thread, but JavaFX doesn't allow to modify any nodes from secondary threads.

I avoided getting the "Not on FX application thread" by using this code:

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // I call the game engine to start the game sequence and I pass root into it for further use
        engine = new GameEngine(root);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                engine.start();
            }
          });
    }
```

inside engine.start() method:

```
public void start() {
        System.out.println("Game started");
        text("Hello, stranger"); // a new Label inside VBox
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) 1000);
                System.out.println("Sleeping...");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error... waiting?");
            }
        } while(this.listener == false); // Listener triggers when user inputs.

        System.out.println("ENTER PRESSED, May proceed");
        text("It worked!");
    }
```

Also, GameEngine extends Thread, and I don't know how it affects anything beside multithreading.

When the code is launched, UI crashed and output gives Sleeping... every second like it should.

Comment: You're overriding `Thread.start` method? This is a terrible idea. Also you don't use the `start` of the superclass. Unless you do this from some other method in the class you loose the ability to execute logic on a different thread. Also note that JavaFX allows you to listen to key presses, but querying the key state is a different matter. It would probably be best to do this event based.

Comment: Side note: `System.out.println("Sleeping...");` is printed out after sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `Thread.sleep()` and/or `while` loop on the JavaFX Application Thread, because that will cause the GUI to stop and wait for your loop to end.

> The solution is to wait using another thread, but JavaFX doesn't allow
>   to modify any nodes from secondary threads.

Yes, you are not supposed to modify the scene graph from non-JavaFX Application Threads, but that doesn't stop you from calling `Platform.runLater()` for the line(s) of codes that does the actual modification. You can also use [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) to achieve this.

It is hard to provide any concrete solution because I have no idea how `listener` flag is being updated.

#### Edit

I didn't notice that the `start()` method belongs to a `Thread` subclass until fabian pointed it out. You should never override `Thread.start()`, and to make it worse, not calling `super.start()` when you override it.

So what happened here is that your `GameEngine` class no longer works like a `Thread`. Calling `engine.start()` simply executes whatever code you have written in the override in whichever thread `engine.start()` is called (which happens to be the JavaFX Application Thread because you have wrapped that in a `Platform.runLater()`).

If you still prefer to extend `Thread`, then you should move the code to override `Thread.run()`. Also note that you should remove `Platform.runLater()` in `initialize()`, and place it in any codes that would affect the GUI.

For example:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    myLabel.setText("User typed" + input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, using multithreading must be wise. One thread waits while main thread edits the layout. Putting

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
  // layout manipulations 
});
```

around layout manipulations works as intended if outside of main thread.